# Opencart Customer Group Login redirect to different pages

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

i had added 3 customer groups my openacart admin, that

1. owner
2. seller
3. guest

what i am looking for when this customer login, each group customers want redirect to different pages...
for example:

if **owner** login - redirect to (ownerpage.php)

if **seller** login - redirect to (sellerpage.php)

if **guest** login - redirect to (guestpage.php)

and give some user page permision also for these group cutomers like admin user permisions...
any idea...? is there is any extension available or have to do any self coding...???

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these pages information pages? Anyway, you could setup redirect in catalog/controller/account/account.php

(Example uses Opencart 1.5.4.1)

Before this line:

```
$this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
```

Add:

```
$id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
   if ($id == 1){
  $this->redirect($this->url->link('custom_page1', '', 'SSL'));
   }
   if ($id == 2){
  $this->redirect($this->url->link('custom_page2', '', 'SSL'));
   }
....
```

Not sure what you mean by page permissions. Maybe you can revise your question to make it clearer.

[EDIT: 2013-01-23]

To restrict access to certain information pages you can check for requested information_id and current user group, then output custom content:

in catalog/controller/information/information.php find line 62:

```
            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    } else {
    ......
```

Add before:

```
$id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
        if ($id == 1 && $information_id == 7){
            $this->data['heading_title'] = 'Not allowed.';
            $this->data['description'] = 'You are not allowed to view this page';
        }
```

Modify condition to your needs.
You can do the same in other controllers, just remove the information_id check, of course.
Of course, you may want to just redirect user to home page or whatever, instead of showing custom message. But I think this is more elegant and less annoying to the user.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean, i tired it, its working now, thanks alots..  and page permission means for example: owner can open any pages my site, but if seller he dont have permission for access download page, newsletter. same if guest also he dont have permision for access return, transaction pages... have any idea.?  thanks

Comment: @B-and-P.. i have to ask some another question almost related to this article. that, how to access group id 2 and 3 customers order information from group id 1 customer account.? i mean my above example owner need to check seller and guest order history... how owner can access other customer data.? i hope you can understand my question, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Now the latest version has this option(I found this in 2.0.2):

$groupid = $this->user->getGroupId();

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you want the customer's id in 2.3.0.2 use: if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getGroupId();
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }